# Rust Diesel Docker Image can't connect to Local Postgres

Tags: postgresql, docker, rust, rust-diesel

I'm building an authentication app with Rust (Actix and Diesel), I've already containerized  it and here's my Dockerfile

```
# Use the Rust official image as a base
FROM rust:latest as builder

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project files into the container
COPY . .

# Install diesel CLI for migration
RUN cargo install diesel_cli --no-default-features --features postgres

# Build the project with cargo
RUN cargo build --release

# Use a smaller base image for the final container
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

# Copy the binary from the previous build stage
COPY --from=builder /app/target/release/author .

RUN apt update && apt install -y openssl libpq-dev pkg-config

EXPOSE 8080

# Set the startup command
CMD ["bash", "-c", "./author diesel migration run && ./author"]
```

However everytime I run the docker with this command:
`docker run --env-file .env -p 8080:8080 355355355/author:latest`

I always got an error with:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'Error connecting to Postgres: Error(None)', src/db.rs:14:25
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace
```

Yes, the error said it's on db.rs, yet the code doesn't show any error itself

```
use diesel::pg::PgConnection;
use diesel::r2d2::{ConnectionManager, Pool, PoolError};
use std::env;

pub type PgPool = Pool<ConnectionManager<PgConnection>>;

pub fn build_pool(db_url: &String) -> Result<PgPool, PoolError> {
    let manager = ConnectionManager::<PgConnection>::new(db_url);
    Pool::builder().build(manager)
}

pub fn connect_pool() -> PgPool {
    let db_url = env::var("DATABASE_URL").expect("DATABASE_URL must be set");
    build_pool(&db_url).expect("Error connecting to Postgres")
}
```

I've searched for around two days but didn't find similar case, other Docker can't connect with Postgres on Stack Overflow is due to env issue, is it similar? Anybody have similar error? Thank you :)

Comment: Could you try printing `db_url` before calling `build_pool`? Just to make sure that the environment variable contains what you think it does (using debug formatting `{:?}` so that if there are control characters they will be visible).

Comment: @Jmb it wasn't being printed, what's the issue there?